# multiple url for single post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have a list of strings in in array.

```
$arr = ('Cab in Hollend', 'Cab in Chicago');
```

and put links in the wordprsss site like **www.mysite.com/cab-in-chicago** and **www.mysite.com/cab-in-hollend**. I want to show the same page for both above URLs. **With different titles**. Which has the id of 75. Currently it is reditrecting to 404

```
$_host = str_replace('-', ' ', str_replace('/', '', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]));
$_list = Array('Minicab in Wembley', 'Minicab in Pinner');

if ( is_404() && (in_array(strtolower($_host), array_map('strtolower', $_ist)))) {

}
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: you have a typo in your array map function. You can basically create a template for the above and modify it to whatever you want. This means you can use the_title() to get the correct title.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an Apache server you can do it by adding to your .htaccess file. Exact line to add depends a little on whether you want to redirect any/all of the various Wordpress URLs or not, but something like:

```
RedirectMatch ^(.*)/cab-in-chicago/?$ $1/cab-on-hollend
```

Granted, this is not exactly what you asked because it is not driven from an array, but redirects done in .htaccess are way, way more performant than doing it in PHP, so do consider it.

Comment: Thankyou. But need different titles on the page

Comment: ah yes, a simple redirect is not sufficient for your needs then. I think if I were doing this I'd write a WordPress plug-in and use the established hooks. Not sure what kind of performance or scalability you require, maybe that is not a concern.